# Questions about CC BY-SA 3.0 text adaptaion and penalties for violations

Tags: cc-by-sa

I am plan to use big non-modified parts of text from Wikipedia under CC BY-SA 3.0 in new text material also licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0: just copy paste it into new material. Than i want create a list on links of the sources with additional notice about license for every source in special part of site about legals: "...This project with great thanks for all authors uses following content listed below. Text materials from Wikipedia licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0..." (and next full list of links to wiki). Is it right and does it enough?

I think that I am not modify text just copy parts of that, so I don't need to other additional notifications. Is it right?

And finally. Which type of penalty I can get if I violate CC BY-SA 3.0, for example, create wrong notifications?

**UPDATED**

Thank you, peoples! I modify landing page. In header at begin of page "All the legal information and links to the data sources you can get by clicking to “i” icon on the top-right corner". Than in the "legal window" listed all links to articles with version of page when info was copied (DD-MM-YY) and link to authors (history of edits) like this (en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wiki&action=history). I made it list of sources like showed in exampled in Wiki: authors, license, time, link to dynamic page. How do you think is enough and no need additional actions?

Comment: You may find [Wikipedia's on page on citing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia) useful. Note especially the advice to permalink to a specific version of the page, as pages may change; clicking the "cite this page" on the left-hand navigation panel of any article will give you article-specific citation advice and examples.

Comment: @Bob, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to my non-lawyer eyes.

Penalties are that you can be sued (or threatened to be sued) by Wikipedia for copyright violation. What they would ask in form of reparation is anybody's guess, but I'd suspect they just politely ask you to fix whatever you did wrong, only resorting to the above if you don't comply.

In the end, it is up to them. It might be wise to contact them and ask in detail. If in any *relevant* doubt, you'll have to hire your very own lawyer  specializing in open source licenses to look into the matter in detail (yes, stuff that we geeks consider a completely irrelevant detail might be legally crucial).

Comment: The text in Wikipedia articles is owned by its authors, not by Wikipedia. So I don't think Wikipedia is in a position to sue for copyright infringement here; the authors, on the other hand, are. Likewise, it's not true that "it's up to them" and I think it's unlikely that they'd be willing to give free legal advice.

Comment: Thank you, peoples! I modify landing page. In header at begin of page "All the legal information and links to the data sources you can get by clicking to “i” icon on the top-right corner". Than in the "legal window" listed all links to articles with version of page when info was copied (DD-MM-YY) and link to authors (history of edits) like this (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wiki&action=history). I made it list of sources like showed in exampled in Wiki: authors, license, time, link to dynamic page. How do you think is enough and no need additional actions?